# What does it mean "NSURLSession API is highly asynchronous"?

Tags: ios, asynchronous, nsurlsession

Let `session` be a configured `NSURLSession` object. A typical code to create a task for this session in Swift would be,

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in 
//my custom completion handler invocation
})
```

My doubt is, does my custom completion handler be invoked in a `dispatch_async` call to avoid blocking the UI thread? Or it need not require, as the API is inherently asynchronous, the method `dataTaskWithRequest(_:completionHandler)` would take care of?

Also in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/dataTaskWithRequest:), the method do not have a completion handler block as you can see. But I've seen many tutorials using this method!?

Comment: The `NSURLSession` API has both the option to use completion handlers (blocks/closures) and delegate methods. I think the delegate method options gives you more fine grained control, but there's in total four protocols and lots of methods (most optional) to adopt.

Comment: The link you provided documents both methods `
dataTaskWithURL(_:)` and `
`dataTaskWithURL(_:completionHandler:)`. The former mentions the need for a delegate.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:

Comment: @NicolasMiari Oh yes! I completely overlooked at the method with completion handler..
What about my doubt about using `dispatch_async`?

Comment: You don't need GCD; it's already asynchronous (both delegate or block modes). It says the handler is called "on the delegate queue". I don't think you need special considerations to rendez-vous on the main/UI thread, but not sure.

Answer (score 2):

The completion handler runs on the queue that you provide, or on its own serial queue.  Unless you explicitly pass in the main queue when you create the session, AFAIK, the only situation where callbacks would block the main thread would be if your completion handler explicitly calls `performSelectorOnMainThread:` or `dispatch_async`/`sync` with `dispatch_get_main_thread`.